# TypeORM: mapping unrelated entities into an array property

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I have the following **unrelated** TypeORM entities (for various reasons, I cannot use One/Many relationships on them):

```js
@Entity()
export class Book {
   @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
   id: number;

   @Column()
   name: string;
}

@Entity()
export class BookCategory {
   @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
   id: number;

   @Column()
   bookId: number;

   @Column()
   name: string;
}
```

With a single book, two assigned categories and the following query:

```js
const query = this.bookRepository
      .createQueryBuilder('book')
      .leftJoinAndSelect(BookCategory, 'category', 'book.id = category.bookId');

return query.execute();
```

I get the following response:

```json
[
  {
    "book_id": 1,
    "book_name": "Lorem Ipsum",
    "category_id": 1,
    "category_name": "non-fiction"
  },
  {
    "book_id": 1,
    "book_name": "Lorem Ipsum",
    "category_id": 2,
    "category_name": "documentary"
  }
]
```

As you see, I get 2 objects. Is there any way I can get the following with a TypeORM query?

```json
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Lorem Ipsum",
    "categories": ["non-fiction", "documentary"]
  }
]
```

I.e. I'm trying to bind a query result to a virtual property `categories`. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible with TypeORM itself, but you could achieve it using `map()` function in the next way:

```
const categories: string[] = query.execute().map((book) => book.category_name );
const book = {id: bookArray[0].book_id, name: bookArray[0].book_name, categories};

//OUTPUT: 
{
  id: 1,
  name: 'Lorem Ipsum',
  categories: [ 'non-fiction', 'documentary' ]
}
```

It's not the cleanist way to do it, but since you are requesting a single book by its ID you will be sure that the `book_id` and `book_name` properties are always the same in every array object.

Also TypeORM recommends using `getMany()` or `getOne()` instead of executing the query:

```
const books: Book[] = await this.bookRepository
  .createQueryBuilder('book')
  .leftJoinAndSelect(BookCategory, 'category', 'book.id = category.bookId')
  .getMany();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm don't known how do his with `queryBuilder`, by on `sql` it would look something like this.

```sql
  SELECT
    book.id as book_id,
    book.name as book_name,
    array_remove(array_agg(bc.name), NULL) as categories
  FROM book
  LEFT JOIN book_category bc ON bc."bookId"=book.id
  GROUP BY book.id
```

I could have made a mistake because I did not check it myself. But it should be something like this.

When executed, you should get a table

| book_id | book_name | categories |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | bookName1 | ['catName', 'catName2'] |
| 2 | bookName2 | ['catName'] |

The main thing here is the `array_agg` and `GROUP BY` method. `GROUP BY` groups data by `book.id`, and `array_agg` groups it into an array

Method `array_remove` needed for remove `NULL` into array if category not found. If book always have category this method can be removed