# TypeORM: How to query ManyToMany relation with string array input to find entities where all strings should exist in the related entity's column?

Tags: javascript, typescript, many-to-many, nestjs, typeorm

I have a `User` entity which has a OneToOne relation to a `Profile` entity and the `Profile` entity has a ManyToMany relation to a `Category` entity.

```
// user.entity.ts

@Entity()
export class User {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @OneToOne(() => Profile, {
    cascade: true,
    nullable: true,
  })
  @JoinColumn() // user owns the relationship (User table contains profileId). Use it only on one side of the relationship
  profile: Profile;
}
```

```
// profile.entity.ts

@Entity()
export class Profile {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: number;

  @OneToOne(() => User, (user: User) => user.profile)
  user: User;

  @ManyToMany(() => Category, (category: Category) => category, {
    cascade: true,
    nullable: true,
  })
  @JoinTable()
  categories: Category[];
}
```

```
// category.entity.ts

@Entity()
export class Category {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: number;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @ManyToMany(() => Profile, (profile: Profile) => profile.categories, {
    nullable: true,
  })
  profiles: Profile[];
}
```

My goal is to get all user entities where category names of the profile are all present in a string array as input e.g. `const categories = ['category1', 'category2']`. So far using [IN](https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/select-query-builder#adding-where-expression) with a query builder brings me close to my goal.

This is the query with IN:

```
const categories = ['category1', 'category2']

const users = await this.usersRepository
  .createQueryBuilder('user')
  .innerJoinAndSelect('user.profile', 'profile')
  .innerJoinAndSelect('profile.categories', 'categories')
  .where('categories.name IN (:...categories)', {
    categories,
  })
  .getMany();
```

I want only users where `category1` AND `category2` are present as names of many to many relations of the profile. With the query above I receive also users where only one of these values are present as names. Is this even possible with my current structure?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59316191/typeorm-mapping-unrelated-entities-into-an-array-property) comes close to mine, but there the OP has unrelated entities.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58475174/how-do-i-query-an-array-in-typeorm) comes also close, but there it's just a string array column for the filtering.

Also I would like to keep my current structure, because may want to add some other columns to the category entity like an order for example.

**Update:**

I decided to use a string array instead of a many to many relation since it satisfies my own requirements.

```
// profile.entity.ts

@Column('text', {
  nullable: true,
  array: true,
})
categories?: string[];
```

The updated query:

```
const categories = ['category1', 'category2']

const users = await this.usersRepository
  .createQueryBuilder('user')
  .innerJoinAndSelect('user.profile', 'profile')
  .where('profile.categories::text[] @> (:categories)::text[]', {
    categories,
  })
  .getMany();
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're using PostgreSQL, you could use the [@> contains array operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html).

```js
const categories = ['category1', 'category2']

// untested code
const users = await this.usersRepository
  .createQueryBuilder('user')
  .innerJoinAndSelect('user.profile', 'profile')
  .innerJoin('profile.categories', 'categories')
  .groupBy('user.id')
  .addGroupBy('profile.id');
  .having('array_agg(categories.name::text) @> ARRAY[:...categories]', {
    categories,
  })
  .getMany();
```

Instead of selecting the categories, it just aggregates the joined categories into an array and checks whether it's a superset of the given array or not. I wasn't able to test this with TypeORM, so I'm just hoping it can deal with the array-building syntax as I couldn't find it anywhere in the documentation. I hope you find this solution helpful.

**Edit**: Added missing groupBy and missing cast, as mentioned in the comments.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It brought me close to what I want. I had to cast one of the sides in the having clause. Either `array_agg(categories.name)::text[]` or `ARRAY[:...categories]::varchar[]`. I also needed to add a `.addGroupBy('profile.id')`, because of the select of the profile. After that I received the expected users. BUT as written in the question I also want to select the categories, so I need a `.innerJoinAndSelect`, but then I need also to add a `.addGroupBy('categories.id')`. If I have now more than one category as input then I receive no results at all. Any hints regarding this?

Comment: You’re doing the right thing by adding the `profile.id` to your group by and casting the array. Selecting and grouping by categories, however, will not work as the `array_agg` function will then yield arrays of one category per row. You could consider joining on `categories` a second time, which can be used in your select. You would probably need a different alias for the second join, though, to avoid name collisions. There are ways to do it with one join and more aggregate functions, but that would require a query with raw results. I’ll update my answer if you can get it to work.

Comment: Thanks for the hints, I already in the meantime I already updated my code to just use a string array in the profile instead of a many to many relation since I spent already quite some time on the issue and this satisfies my current app requirements. Also I want to finish something. If I encounter that issue again in the future with a needed many to many relation I will try to solve it with your hints. Will upvote your answer anyways since it brought me pretty close to the solution